# Python counter / Prob with the loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I got 2 list of coordinates, X and Y. If we plot them, we would see a more or less circular trajectory. My objective is to count, the number of circle trajectory that is done.

**The idea of the algorithm :**

1..I calculate the average center of the trajectory

```
Center = (int(sum(X)/len(X)), int(sum(Y)/len(Y)))
```

Center will be X0 and Y0

2..K is the counter.
I look where the point is, and everytime it get back in the south / west area, K += 1. Moreover, until i get out of this area, K doesn't stack up anymore.

```
        K = 0
        c = 0
        while c < len(X):
            if X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                c += 1
                continue
            elif X[c] < X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                c += 1
                continue
            elif X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                c += 1
                continue
            else:
                K += 1
                # On saute les points suivants dans le même quart
                while X[c] < X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                    c += 1
```

It works, but not if my final points are in this area, in which case, i get an out of range with the while X[c] < X0 and Y[x] < Y0.

I tried this code, that i found better, but i can't get it to work :

```
for c in range(len(X)):
                if X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                    continue
                elif X[c] < X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                    continue
                elif X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                    continue
                else:
                    K += 1
                    while X[c] < X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                        # Here i need a continue but on the for, not on the while...
```

Any help would be priceless.

Thanks !

Comment: How about this: `K =  sum(1 for i, point in enumerate(X) if point < X0 and Y[i] < Y0)`. Not sure if the inequalities are correct; you confused me there. I can write it as an answer if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. didn't know the formulation, but it doesn't solve the problem. I don't skip the point following the one counted.

Comment: The goal is to count the first occurence, then to skip all the point that are following in the south west area. Once we get out o this area, the next point in it will be counted, and so on. With the code above, i get 42 rotation, when i only have 5. That's because it counts every point in the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find below a solution, not really beautiful, but working.
It checks where the last position is. If it's in the 1/4 of the circle currently being checked, it changes the checking area to the opposite 1/4.

```
if (X[len(X)-1] >= X0 and Y[len(X)-1] >= Y0) or (X[len(X)-1] < X0 and Y[len(X)-1] >= Y0) or (X[len(X)-1] >= X0 and Y[len(X)-1] < Y0):
            while c < len(X):
                if X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                    c += 1
                    continue
                elif X[c] < X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                    c += 1
                    continue
                elif X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                    c += 1
                    continue
                else:
                    K += 1
                    # skip the following points in the same quarter
                    while X[c] < X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                        c += 1
        else:
            while c < len(X):
                if X[c] <= X0 and Y[c] <= Y0:
                    c += 1
                    continue
                elif X[c] > X0 and Y[c] <= Y0:
                    c += 1
                    continue
                elif X[c] <= X0 and Y[c] > Y0:
                    c += 1
                    continue
                else:
                    K += 1
                    # skip the following points in the same quarter
                    while X[c] > X0 and Y[c] > Y0:
                        c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that I understood the problem correctly, What you are looking for is to break out of single loop in a nested loop? You can use an exception to return from inner loop

```
class Found(Exception): pass
for c in range(len(X)):
       try:
                if X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                    continue
                elif X[c] < X0 and Y[c] >= Y0:
                    continue
                elif X[c] >= X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                    continue
                else:
                    K += 1
                    while X[c] < X0 and Y[c] < Y0:
                         #do whatever you want here               
                         raise Found  #raise exception when condition occurs
        except Found:
               print(K)
```

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with the class and exception, so i don't completely get the code up there. If i try it, i got 1 rotation, looks to me like it stopped at the first one he found.

Comment: The idea, is to look my value X and Y. When i enter the South - West part of my circle, i say that i did 1 lap. Then, i skip all the point that are in this south - west area after the first one. The next lap will be counted only if before i have a point in the south-west area, i first get out of it at elast once.